# QGIS: concatenate_unique several columns in attributes table

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression, concatenation

I have a table with points representing villages. Its columns represent the place of the village in different historical periods. Sometimes the names are the same in different columns.

Now, I want to create a new column that would merge all possible and unique names of a village across history into one string.

#### Example:

| antiquity | middle_ages | modern | 19th c. | 20th c. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sermylia | Hermylia | Ormylia | Ormylia | Ormylia |
| Brana | Brya |  | Brya |  |

#### Expected results:

- Sermylia, Hermylia, Ormylia
- Brana, Brya

I thought that `concatenate_unique` would be my solution, but apparently I cannot make it process several columns.

Answer (score 6):

`concatenate_unique` works between records, for a single column (or expression). To work per row, you can instead rely on `array` functions.

The following code also removes the null entries

```
array_to_string(
 array_distinct(
  array_filter( 
   array("antiquity" , "middle_ages" , "modern" , "19th c." , "20th c." ),
   @element is not null
  )
 ),
 ','
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Even shorter:

```
array_to_string ( array_remove_all(  array_distinct( map_avals( attributes( ))),''))
```

*See result in preview:*
[image]

Comment: Great alternative if all fields are to be included. I believe you would still need to filter for nulls though, else an empty string is kept

Comment: You're right with both points. Added an alternative using `array_remove_all()`.